# Yii2: is it possible to filter out some query from being logged into Yii Debugger?

Tags: php, yii2

I love Yii2 log system, but I'd like to 'narrow' a bit the log avoiding logging of query like

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tbl_product`
```

or RBAC-related like

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_auth_assignment` WHERE `user_id`='1'
```

Where and how can I customize/configure the logging system to exclude queries **by sql text** (not by log category/level as usually)?

I know I can extend FileTarget to *avoid some messages from being written on disk*. For example:

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

class CustomFileTarget extends \yii\log\FileTarget
{   
    // this is an override
    public function collect($messages, $final)
    {

        foreach ($messages as $index  => $message) {
            // See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html#$messages-detail
            if ($message[2] == 'yii\\db\\Command::query') {

                $is_full_cols       = (stripos($message[0], "SHOW FULL COLUMNS")===0);
                $is_create_table    = (stripos($message[0], "SHOW CREATE TABLE")===0);

                if ($is_full_cols OR $is_create_table)  {
                    unset($messages[$index]);
                }
            } 


        }
        parent::collect($messages, $final);
    }
}
```

then configure my app to use it

```
'log'       => [

        'targets'   => [
            ....
            [
                'class'         => 'common\components\CustomFileTarget',
                'categories'    => ['*'],
            ],
        ],
```

But I'd like to AVOID these message be found in the Yii Debugger's database panel. Or, better, to **complete remove logging of these SQLs at all**. (Probably this need to extend active query base class)

Doing more lookup into the Yii2 code, I found where ALL of SQLs were logged: it's in the file `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php` in the function `queryInternal`. I'm thinking that I should override this class to override this function, and override `ActiveQuery` and `ActiveRecord` classes to force these to use my overridden `Command` class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I found that there is `log` component set the in the config/web.php which you could extend the `yii\log\FileTarget` to customise what is being log.

There is also the Yii Debugger which I think is what you are referring to. I'm not sure how this can be customise but you can take a look at : [cache site](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TgfcF2NL7agJ:www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-debugger.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Comment: If I extend `FileTarget`, of course _into the log file_ the messages I discard will not be logged. I'll now try to create a custom panel to filter out useless query messages.